# Removing event listener / onclick in the function that is the onclick function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove an event listener in a function that is the same function that is called by `onclick`.

The following example illustrates my problem. The reason I am trying to use that kind of construction is to pass a function to a view object so that it can add it as an `onclick` function to created elements.

```
"use strict";

// Do I need var fun = function()... here or I could use only function fun() { ....}?
var fun = function(obj, num) {
  alert(obj.id + ' ' + num);
  obj.onclick = ""; // Version 1. This seems to work
  //obj.removeEventListener('click', ); // Version 2. What should I add after the comma to remove EventListener?

}

setFn(fun);

function setFn(fn) {

  var funct = fn;

  var val = 10;
  var elem = document.getElementById('test');
  // The next function works with and without return. What are the differences? Are there any possible memory leaks?
  elem.onclick = function() { funct(this, 11); }; // Version 1. Why in this case 'this' is not referring to the global 'window'?
  //elem.addEventListener('click', function() {funct(this, val); }); // Version 2.
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: Yes, I have. I does not say anything about removing it in the same function that I am calling out when clicking the element. Nor does it say anything about memory leaks. I know that there are some cases when memory leaks can occur. Unfortunately, I don't know all the corner cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an event listener you need to pass exactly the same function that was added.

```
"use strict";

var fun = function(obj, num, originalEventHandler) {
  alert(obj.id + ' ' + num);
  obj.removeEventListener('click', originalEventHandler);
}

function setFn(fn) {
  var element = document.getElementById('test');

  element.addEventListener('click', function eventHandler() {
    fn(this, 11, eventHandler);
  });
}

setFn(fun);
```

This should work.

Comment: Why didn't I come up with passing the function as an argument... However why is it safe to pass `this` as an argument in these scenarios? Why does it point to the element rather than the global window or some other thing?

Comment: Becuase it is such a desired behavior to reference to the element on which the event was fired the value of `this` inside the handler is a reference to the element. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Search for "The value of `this` within the handler".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way. You have no reference to the anonymous function you passed to `.addEventListener()` in version 2, so it can't be removed.

One possibility would be to name the currently anonymous function, and pass it in to `funct` as a third argument.

```
elem.addEventListener('click', function f() {funct(this, val, f); });
```

Then `fun` can use that to remove the listener.

```
var fun = function(obj, num, bound_fn) {
  alert(obj.id + ' ' + num);
  if (bound_fn) {
    obj.removeEventListener('click', bound_fn);
  }
}
```